# unable to create quarkus project in eclipse(Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)) getting an error "Remote host terminated the handshake"

Tags: java, eclipse, quarkus, jboss-tools

I am trying to create new Quarkus project using jee eclipse

1. Create new project using new project wizard in jee eclipse(Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0))
2. select Quarkas project, click next and continue for next few windows and click finish
   Now, in eclipse an error window shows up with the below message
   "Creating quarkus project has encountered problem "Remote host terminated the handshake"

tried to find the solution in docs and google search nothing helped

Error Log from eclipse:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1714)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.jboss.tools.quarkus.core.code.model.QuarkusModelRegistry.zip(QuarkusModelRegistry.java:176)
    at org.jboss.tools.quarkus.ui.wizard.CodeProjectWizardController.getZip(CodeProjectWizardController.java:67)
    at org.jboss.tools.quarkus.ui.wizard.CodeProjectWizardController.run(CodeProjectWizardController.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job$1.run(Job.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Did it also create an entry in the Error Log? The tool developers could use that kind of information.

Comment: Thank you, updated with the error log entry from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to create new quarkus project with Eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0) and JBT 4.26.0.Final and it works for me.

Can I ask you to provide more steps with more info?
for example:

1. Window -> Perspective -> quarkus perspective
2. File -> New -> Quarkus project
3. Quarkus stream: ...

I can create and run quarkus project w/o any issues.
You can also try to:

1. remove your .m2/repository folder and reinstall eclipse
2. check if you have any network problems

Comment: not an answer, should be a comment or flag

Comment: Thank you for helping out, already tried the suggested solutions but did not work

Comment: @Learn-techie Can I ask you to provide more detailed steps?